# Generating a text file (log) in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have checked Google, and the suggested answers here, but have had no luck unfortunately.

I was wondering how can I take a text output from the console, like a exception and store it on a .txt file, the file would have to be created by the program when the first log entry is to be written, ideally.

So each time there is a SQL Exeption for example in my try/catch block I need to call the method to write into the text file, I was wondering if anyone knows of something like this.

Any kind of tip, help or source to find this information would be really appreciated

Example of the current exception catch flow when deleting a User (Usuario):

```
Private Sub borrarUsuario()

    Try

        If idUsuario > 0 Then

            result = MessageBox.Show("¿Realmente desea borrar este usuario?", "Eliminar Usuario", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

            If result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

                gestorUsuario.eliminarUsuario(idUsuario)
                ActualizarTabla()

            End If

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Por favor seleccione un usuario primero", "Usuarios", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

End Sub
```

This calls the UsusarioGestor class which contains all the methods related to the Usuario class.

```
    public void eliminarUsuario(int idUsuario) {

       try {

       Usuario Usuario = UsuarioRepository.Instance.GetById(idUsuario);
       UsuarioRepository.Instance.Delete(Usuario);
       UsuarioRepository.Instance.Save();
       }

       catch (DataAccessException ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
       }
    }
```

This is turn calls the User Repository which makes the connection to the database.

```
    private void DeleteUsuario(Usuario Usuario)
    {
        try
        {
            DataBaseAccess.simpleStoredProcedureRequest("pa_usuario_eliminar", new SPP[] { 
                new SPP("id_usuario", Usuario.Id.ToString()),
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));

        }

    }//Fin Metodo Delete
```

Comment: [File.AppendText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx)

Comment: @Gserg I came for an answer then came again. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some sample code which catches an exception? When you add further code to open a file and write an exception, what problem do you have? Have you considered writing to the windows event log instead?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'll add the catch to the post. The problem was that no solution worked, I just came from college so I was goin to try the appendText method. The only issue I see is the need to specify a file path that is valid.

I am afraid I don't really know about the windows event log, this is my first time trying this. I just know I need to save somewhere all the exceptions the systems throws for later reviewing.

Comment: Unfortunately, _had no luck_ and _no solution worked_ are not very helpful descriptions. If you write to the windows event log you don't have to worry about opening and closing files and finding a valid output location etc. You just call the method to write to the windows event log. Why don't you try some research in that direction, call the method to write to the event log, and if you have a problem, write a specific question. In fact, right now, go to the start menu and type 'Event Viewer' and take a look at it. This is where your messages will end up - in the 'application' folder.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, sorry english is not my first language and my professor is utterly incompetent. What you've told me sounds awesome though, I'll look it up

Comment: Its really just a matter of explaining your specific issue. No one can help problems like 'it didn't work'. If you have a specific question, alter your original question